# Consequences of using smaller replacement pulley/jockey wheels in the rear derailleur

Tags: derailleur-rear, compatibility, frugal, microshift

I have a new rear derailleur (Microshift Advent X) which uses somewhat oversized cog wheels with **12** and 14 teeth. I am known to wear these wheels during the winter season, so I am already planning for spare parts.

I have a small stash of smaller 11 teeth pulley/jockey wheels and I wonder if I could install them when the time comes, instead of looking for matching larger spares. The benefits are that the 11-teeth parts are quite more widespread, but what are the possible problems that this could create?

Here are some negative things that I can imagine, but maybe I am missing something or underestimating the consequences.

1. Clearance problems between pulley/jockey wheels, derailleur cage and chain passing through them. I can imagine that squeezing *larger* cogs could cause that, but with smaller ones the clearance should increase.
2. Increased chain friction because of sharper angles when links are wrapping smaller cogs. I could not care less about it. The bulk of my friction problems in that area come from clogged bushings/bearings inside the pulley wheels; something that better seals, not more teeth, should help with.
3. Change of the optimal chain length. I can imagine that with fewer teeth I'd need to remove a few links from the chain? Or is it the other way around, and the chain must grow?
4. Worse chain retention (chain jumping inside the derailleur). I wonder if this will be noticeable given how constrained the chain inside the cage is, and with clutched derailleur keeping it tensioned.

Comment: I think the typical recommendation of Kogel and Ceramicspeed is that you should add links when installing their large pulley wheels. From experience, going from dual 11t to 12/14t pulleys doesn’t seem to need additional links despite the recommendation. Actually, I size my chain using the big ring/big cog plus 2 pins method, which bypasses the RD cage entirely.

Comment: 5. Increased clearance between jockey wheel and sprocket. Since shifting relies on the angle between chain and sprocket, I guess that increasing the clearance (and by that decreasing the chain angle while shifting) could lead to problems with shifting. I think, that would be the main consideration (apart from having to take a link out of the chain).

Comment: @WeiwenNg Mechanically, the difference between 11ti11t and 12t/14t should be exactly one link: The 12t has 0.5 teeth extra and the 14t has 1.5 teeth extra to wrap the chain halfway around each wheel. That's a total of 2 teeth, i.e. 1 link of the chain.

Comment: 6. Less allowable range for the cassette: Wrap around of the chain around the jockey wheels adds to the amount by which the derailleur can lengthen/shrink the chain. If your derailleur is already at its limits with your cassette, smaller jockey wheels and a shortened chain may break its neck.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I used some generic 10 t pulleys on a Shimano XT derailleur that originally used 11t pulleys, on a 3x9 speed bike. I noticed no negative effect whatsoever (somewhere between year 2000 an 2004) If I did that on my current XT derailleur (bought circa 2010) the chain would rub on a cage plate "protrusion" that goes towards the other plate.

Comment: Chain friction will increase because the links have to bend further. You'll lose  .5 -1 W. The reason for the super-expensive dinner-plate jockey wheels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am now in position to answer my question, as I've obtained practical results of an experiment described in the question.

I managed to destroy an upper pulley wheel when it met a stub. The rest of the derailleur was undamaged.

[image: Broken upper pulley]

The damaged guide pulley had 12 teeth (not 13 teeth as I originally miscounted). I only had 11-teeth replacements from SRAM in my reserves. So I went ahead and replaced it. I also shortened the chain by 2 half-links as I felt it was just a bit too long as well.

The main adjustment that I had to do to make it work was to ensure that the cage would not touch the cassette when climbing from the next-to-biggest cog to the largest cog. The B-tension screw of the derailleur was turned until there was a gap between these parts. A smaller diameter of the replacement part brought the cage closer to the cassette, so that had to be accounted for:

[image: B-tension-affected distance]

During the next two weeks, the repaired derailleur worked without noticeable differences compared to how it shifted before.

I have just received and installed a replacement 12-teeth upper pulley wheel from the manufacturer (the part is not available aftermarket yet). Again, I have not noticed any difference in shifting.

Comment: Nice work - thank you for the completion.  TBH probably didn't even need to remove any links in the chain.

Answer (score 2):

When people put in wider than stock pulleys, one possible outcome is the chain winds up getting jammed between the tension pulley and the cage. That can result in a destroyed derailleur and/or frame. This may not be common per se, but I've seen it enough that I'm very conservative about never using anything but the original thickness.

Comment: In an ironic twist of fate, I've just destroyed my upper pulley wheel when it met a tree :-( https://i.stack.imgur.com/dufpR.jpg Let's see if I will be able to make the derailleur work with the smaller 11t replacement.